# pandas fillna(method='ffill') vs ffill()

Tags: python, dataframe

Hi My dearly pandas gurus,

I was trying to forward fill missing data in a dataframe, these were the two ways I compared, the ffill() outperformed fillna(method='ffill') tremendously, so here are questions popping up, are they doing the same thing to the dataframe, if they are same, why are they so different in performance. is ffill() implemented in cython?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, 2, np.nan, 0],
                [3, 4, np.nan, 1],
                [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                [np.nan, 3, np.nan, 4]],
               columns=list('ABCD'))
df.fillna(method='ffill')
#vs
df.ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the difference. I'm using Pandas 1.0.5

[image]

Comment: This actually is rather interesting because it _does_ appear to show a notable difference

Comment: It is significant in the t-test sense, but I'd consider them broadly equally performant for everyday use.

Comment: forgot to mention that i was using pandas 0.23, that maybe the issue?